# Send post request to express without changing the url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a login form. I'm using angularjs' ng-submit. When the submit button is clicked, I want the post method to be called in the server without changing the url.

The `post` of express requires a url to which it responds. If my login screen's url is `http://localhost:2000/login` and when submit is clicked, I want the `post` to be called for the same url `http://localhost:2000/login`.

And I don't understand how to use the `url` key of the `$http`.

The login html:

```
<form ng-controller="loginController" ng-submit="loginFunc()">
<input type="text" name="" ng-model="login">
<input type="password" ng-model="password" name="">
<input type="submit" value="login" name="">
```

The controller:

```
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.login = ""
  $scope.password = "";
  $scope.loginArray = [];
  $scope.loginFunc() {
    $scope.loginArray.push($scope.login);
    $scope.loginArray.push($scope.password);
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'loginClick',
      data: $scope.loginArray
    })
  }
})
```

The server.js:

```
app.get('/login', function(request, response) { //the file sent when /login is requested
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/staticFolder/view/login.html");
})

app.post('/loginCheck', function(request, response) { //call this when submit button is clicked without change in url
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body) + "req");
})
```

Comment: Any error are you getting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending login details as an object instead of sending as in array.It will make your life easy.

```
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loginFunc() {
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/loginCheck', //not loginClick make sure you have a route to handle this.
                data: {
                    login: $scope.login,
                    password: $scope.password
                }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                //Success handling
            }, function(err) {
                //Error handling
            });
    }
})
```

You must respond in each and Every route

> ***Edit 1***
>   use backend as: to use same url `/login` but with different http verbs(`get` and `post`)

```
app.get('/login', function(request, response) { //the file sent when /login is requested
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/staticFolder/view/login.html");
});
app.post('/login', function(request, response) { //call this when submit button is clicked without change in url
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body) + "req");
  /*
    below will be the logic for handling your interest.
  */
  someIOCall(function Handler(err,resultJson){
    if(err)
      return res.status(500).end();
    res.status(200).end(resultJson)
  })    
})
```

It should work in scenario.

Comment: i dont think anyone understood my problem. when i want to display the login.html, the url is `../login.html`. When I click on the login button, I want to call the `post` method. The `post` method needs a url. I dont want to specify that url because I want to stay in the same url and the post method should respond to the same

Comment: 1.To render login form the url will be `/login` not `/login.html` and 2. if you do  an ajax request you have to handle data whatever you get...

And please share the exact issue what do you want to achieve is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should send POST data as an object, not as an array, if not express does not really know which param has which value.

Also, a string like 'loginClick' does not work as an url.

try something like:

```
$scope.loginFunc = function(){
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'/login',
            data: {
               login: $scope.login,
               password: $scope.password
            }
        })
    }
```

Not 100% sure is '/login' is enough for url, if not try specifying the absolute url with port etc.

if you want to post to '/login', you'll have to adjust your express route as well:

```
app.post('/login', function(request,response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body)+"req");
})
```

Comment: when I first display the  login screen, then request is sent to server and  it searches for the request parameters in `app.post`. I want to do that only when login button is clicked to check the login.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion about sending as object and not as an array.